# Custom label for x axis on nvd3 graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am fairly new to graphs using javascript and  started using d3 and nvd3 for a project now. I am trying to plot a multi bar chart provided by nvd3 module. I am successful in plotting the data however, I am not able to customize the values for x axis for each series. I believe it is taking integer values for x to plot the graph. My question is how can I show some custom value like X, Y, Z instead of 1, 2, 3 for each graph.

Below is my code i am using

```
var data = [{
        "key" : "Step 1",
        "values" : [{"y" : 5,"x" : 2,},{"y" : 4,"x" : 1,}, {"y" : 4,"x" : 0,}]
    }, {
        "key" : "Step 2",
        "values" : [{"y" : 4,"x" : 0}, {"y" : 5,"x" : 2 }, {"y" : 6,"x" : 1 }]
    }, {
        "key" : "Step 3",
        "values" : [{"y" : 5,"x" : 2}, {"y" : 4,"x" : 0 }, {"y" : 5,"x" : 1 }]
    }];

    var chart;
    var tickValues = ['X','Y','Z'];
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        chart = nv.models.multiBarChart().margin({
            bottom : 100
        }).transitionDuration(300).delay(0).groupSpacing(0.5);
        chart.multibar.hideable(true);
        chart.reduceXTicks(true).staggerLabels(true);
        chart.xAxis.showMaxMin(false)
            //.tickValues(tickMarks)
            .tickFormat(function(x){
                    return tickValues[x]
                }
            );
        chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
        d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(data).call(chart);
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
                    return chart;
    });
```

if i plot the graph using the above code, the graph is generating properly but the Custom Values for X axis are completely out of order. I want X to be printed where value in data array hss x = 0, Y for data array x = 1 and so on. But right now its coming randomly.

I tried passing the data as

```
var data = [{ "key" : "Step 1", "values" : [{"y" : 5,"x" : "Z",},{"y" : 4,"x" : "Y",}, {"y" : 4,"x" : "X",}]
```

So that I can plot the desired value of each axis as mention in data, but it does not work. :(

Is there a better way to keep the values in sync ? Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or somewhere where we can view the code in action?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VBtEx/ here is the code. I could not generate the graph because nvd3 is not hosted anywhere. I had to download the src code and added in my page. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I believe that you can't really do this with NVD3 -- it wasn't meant to support this. You would either have to modify the source code or start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have `key: Step 1`, that represents the label for the Series (used in the tooltip typically).

As for the xAxis labels, they ARE in fact displaying correctly, as the xAxis label is the x data. If you take your example and change all the `x : 0` to `x : "Beer"`, you'll see what I mean.

Here's a jsFiddle showing the change to the `x : 0` data: http://jsfiddle.net/essboyer/ZKqkJ/